# Sencha Touch belongsTo association using Store on Datalist

Tags: associations, sencha-touch-2, store, datalist, belongs-to

I want to get belongsTo record on datalist and show parent record fields.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Customer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: ['Id', 
        'EMail'],   
        hasMany:  [{
            model: 'MyApp.model.OutstandingInvoice',
            name: 'OutstandingInvoice',
            primaryKey: 'Id',
            foreignKey: 'customerId',
            foreignStore: 'OutstandingInvoices'
        }]
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.OutstandingInvoice', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
        'InvoiceDate', 
        'InvoiceID',
        'customerId'
        ],
        belongsTo: [{
            model: 'MyApp.model.Customer',
            name: 'Customer',
            primaryKey: 'Id',
            foreignKey: 'customerId',
            foreignStore: 'Customers'
        }]
    }
});


Ext.define('MyApp.store.OutstandingInvoices', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.OutstandingInvoice',        
        storeId: 'OutstandingInvoiceStore',        
        proxy: {
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            type: 'ajax',            
            url : 'http://localhost/getOutstandingInvoices',            
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: false
    }
});


Ext.define('MyApp.store.Customers', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.Customer',      
        storeId: 'CustomerStore',        
        proxy: {
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            type: 'ajax',            
            url : 'http://localhost/getCustJList',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: false,
        sorters: [{
            property : 'FName',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }]
    }
});



Ext.define('MyApp.view.OutstandingInvoices', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'outstandingInvoicesXType',
    config: {
        cls : 'invoiceSummaryCls',
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Outstanding Invoices'
        },
        {
            xtype : 'list',
            scrollable: false,
            store: 'OutstandingInvoiceStore',
            cls : 'p10',
            itemTpl: [
            '<div>Invoice # {InvoiceID}</div>',
            '<div>{InvoiceDate}</div>',        
            '<div>{Customer.Email}</div>', // I want to show Customer name here as its belongsTo Customer
            ],
            listeners: {
                itemtap:function (list, index, targe, rec, e, eOpts) {                    
                    console.log(rec)
                }
            }
        }
        ] 
    }

});
```

I want to show Customer name in datalist but having issue with association or Xtemplate
I am getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.XTemplate#apply] Cannot read property 'Email' of undefined
```

Please help me out in this.

Comment: try autoLoad:true in Customers store

Comment: This won't help that specific error but FYI, you have a typo in your customer field config : EMail instead of Email

Comment: You'll need to move your proxy onto the model otherwise sencha won't know how to load data for the association

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading this [article](http://appointsolutions.com/2012/07/using-model-associations-in-sencha-touch-2-and-ext-js-4), its quite lengthy but the final List section is similar to your example.

I think the key point is you're not going to need separate stores. Sencha is going to create those automatically off the back of the associations. Make sure you move the proxies onto the models and set autoLoad: true